# obtain a collection from 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good morning, everyone,
I have 4 tables:

**Organizations**

- id
- name

**User**

- id
- name

**Organization_user**

- user_id
- organization_id
- role_id

**Role**

- id
- label

So, I would like to obtain, for a user, all his organizations with the role he has in them.
I can't correctly understand which relationship in Eloquent I should use...

### EDIT:

Thank you for your answer. But I'm still blocking my relationships.
I would like to list all organizations for a single user with the role they occupy.
A user can only have one role in each organization. 
Here are my current relationships:

**OrganizationUser Model**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OrganizationUser extends Pivot
{
  public function role()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
  }
}
```

**User Model**

```php
    public function organizations() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class)->using(OrganizationUser::class);
    }
```

**My Controller**

```php
public function ShowOrganizations() {
        $user = User::with('organizations')->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        return view('dashboard/organization', [
          'user' => $user,
        ]);
      }
```

Currently I get the relationship contained in my pivot table but I don't get the "label" of the role contained in the "Role" table, I only get the user id and the organization id contained in the "Organization_user" table.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If there are many organizations, then only use organization entity. Otherwise if there is only one organization then you can simply omit the organization from the relation. Then use many to many relationship with role and user.

Comment: Create your own model for the `organization_user` table. From that point, it will be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try the joins

```
$role = 'Your role id here';

$result = DB::table('Organization_user as ou')
    ->join('Organizations as o', 'o.id', '=', 'ou.organization_id')
    ->join('User as u', 'u.id', '=', 'ou.user_id')
    ->select('o.name', 'u.name as username')
    ->where('ou.role_id', $role)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

1) User has many to many relationship with Organizations.

```
class User extends Model
{

   public function organizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class)->using(OrganizationUser::class);
    }
}
```

2) You will need to add a relationship in pivot model for role.

```
class OrganizationUser extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

And this should solve your relationship problems.

Now you can query all users with their `organizations` and associated roles.

Comment: Hi Mike !
Thank's for your reply !
I've update my question with more informations :)